# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist, cannot find my error

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

    try {

        createTable();
        insertRecordIntoTable("leo","123");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}

private static void createTable() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String sequence = "CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20";
    String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE DBUSER1("
            + "USER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, "
            + "USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
            + "PASSWORD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
            + "PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID) "
            + ")";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(createTableSQL);

        System.out.println(createTableSQL);

        // execute create SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate(createTableSQL);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sequence);




        System.out.println("Table \"dbuser\" is created!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}

private static void insertRecordIntoTable(String username, String password) throws SQLException {


        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER1"
                + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES"
                + "(ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?)";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            // execute insert SQL stetement

            preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }

}
```

I cannot find the error when I try to create a sequence for my table.

When I try to insert some data in my table with the sequence it says it doesn't exist, but I did create it. Also I am not sure if i need a preparedStatement.setInt(1, seq_id.nextval); it gives an error but im not quite sure how I would do this

Comment: Once you ran your program and look in - for example - SQL Developer, do the sequence and/or table exist?

Comment: the table exist but the sequence doesnt

Comment: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be adding the schema name (owner) before the name of sequence:

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE some_nameOf_schema.ID_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20
```

Comment: i changed it into this String SEQUENCE = "CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NO CYCLE";

Comment: i still get the error ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You're preparing a statement with one SQL text, and executing the statement with two different SQL texts;

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(createTableSQL);

preparedStatement.executeUpdate(createTableSQL);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sequence);
```

...which is actually invalid according to the docs;

> **int executeUpdate(String sql)
>                     throws SQLException**
>   Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.
>   *Note:This method **cannot be called on a PreparedStatement** or CallableStatement.*

What you need to do is to prepare and execute two different statements;

```
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(createTableSQL);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sequence);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, it doesn't make much sense to `CREATE` database objects every time your application starts up, because this is something that's usually done only once, when you install/upgrade the database/schema the application uses.

However, if you really have to do it this way, the current solution could be improved so that the following points are considered:

- Only execute the `CREATE` statements when the objects do not yet exist in the DB. This can be done by first inspecting the [`USER_OBJECTS` data dictionary view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general010.htm).
- Use a plain `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement` for executing the [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) (prepared statements are only useful for [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) operations that use input variables)
- Handle JDBC resources (`Connection` / `Statement` / `ResultSet`) concisely and safely through the [try-with-resources construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Here's how the code could look like:

```
// query constants
private static final String CHECK_DB_OBJECT = 
            "SELECT 1 FROM user_objects WHERE object_name = ?";

private static final String CREATE_SEQUENCE = 
        "CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999" +
        " MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE DBUSER1("
        + "USER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, "
        + "USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
        + "PASSWORD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
        + "PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID) "
        + ")";

/* clip the main method etc. */    

/**
* Creates the table and sequence only if they do not already exist.
*/
private static void createTableAndSequenceIfAbsent() {

    try (Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
         PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection
                    .prepareStatement(CHECK_DB_OBJECT)) {

        if (!dbObjectExists(ps, "ID_SEQ")) {
            executeDDL(dbConnection, CREATE_SEQUENCE);
        }            
        if (!dbObjectExists(ps, "DBUSER1")) {
            executeDDL(dbConnection, CREATE_TABLE);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}

private static boolean dbObjectExists(PreparedStatement ps,
        String objectName) throws SQLException {

    ps.setString(1, objectName);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    // if the #CHECK_DB_OBJECT query returned a row, the object exists
    return rs.next();
}

private static void executeDDL(Connection c, String sql)
        throws SQLException {

    try (Statement st = c.createStatement()) {
        st.execute(sql);
    }
}
```